# LogMeIn GoToWebinar SDK responds with 403 Access denied

Tags: c#, sdk, http-status-code-403, logmein

I want to get a list of all Attendees of a Webinar (all sessions) by using the GoToWebinar SDK (NuGet package).
My account, dev user, products (licenses), consumer key, consumer secret are all set up okay.
By authenticating the OAuth2Api I get a access Token. So far so good...
When I use:

```
var webinarsApi = new WebinarsApi();
var webinarData = webinarsApi.getWebinar(accessToken, organizerKey, webinarKey);
```

I get a good response with a WebinarByKey object, filled with information of the Webinar.
But when I call:

```
var attendeesData = webinarsApi.getAttendeesForAllWebinarSessions(accessToken, organizerKey, webinarKey, 0, 20);
```

It throws an 403 Exception (Access denied).
I have tried it in a console app (.NET Framework 4.7.2) and .NET Code 3.1.
Even Postman replies with a 403.
I think there is a missing link somewhere, but can't find where. Who can help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access webinar registrants using your LogMeIn developer account? This account is responsible for the creation of the OAuth app but does not equal a LogMeIn product account (e.g. GoToWebinar product) that has access to GoToWebinar.

As explained here: https://developer.goto.com/guides/HowTos/08_HOW_webhooks/

Make sure you are using the OAuth2 Access Token from an account that has GoToWebinar listed in it's product (and a list of webinars/registrants).